# Smth trouble with tty2

Tags: ubuntu, console, tty, systemd

In last time I setting Ubuntu 14.10 and it works so good. And it using tty1 by default console. But yesterday evening i change setting for "xbindkeys". And now, i detected, that ubuntu is starting by tty2 and bind keys doesnt works.

To see it,  tty2 - which is working now.

```
root@stand2:/# systemctl status getty@tty2
getty@tty2.service - Getty on tty2
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service; enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:agetty(8)
           man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
           http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
```

And, tty1 which doesn't using.

```
root@stand2:/# systemctl status getty@tty1
getty@tty1.service - Getty on tty1
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service; enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-04-01 15:32:34 NOVT; 56min ago
     Docs: man:agetty(8)
           man:systemd-getty-generator(8)
           http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html
 Main PID: 1888 (login)
   CGroup: /system.slice/system-getty.slice/getty@tty1.service
           ‣ 1888 /bin/login --

Apr 01 15:32:34 stand2 systemd[1]: Starting Getty on tty1...
Apr 01 15:32:34 stand2 systemd[1]: Started Getty on tty1.
Apr 01 15:33:28 stand2 login[1888]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user root by LOGIN(uid=0)
```

How to decide this problem, I tried very much ways.